# Installing Keras for R - how might I solve an error message when installing Keras (ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes)?

Tags: r, keras, installation, error-handling

I'm trying to install Keras for R

My professor gave me this link to download it: https://hastie.su.domains/ISLR2/keras-instructions.html

I get an error message after I run the 3rd line of code:

```
`install.packages("keras")
reticulate::install_miniconda()
keras::install_keras(method = "conda", python_version = "3.10")`
```

The error message looks like this:

[error message in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIbQO.png)

I'm running with R-4.3.2 and Windows 10

I tried a lot of things by googling and asking chatGPT.

In the end I decided to reinstall R and Rstudio entirely and as far as I know I also deleted all related files/documents from my PC before reinstalling.

After reinstalling, I still got the same error message.

I'm looking for any solution that might work as I have no clue what I can try anymore

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem in the end.

In case anyone else runs into the same issue: all I had to do was change the python_version to 3.8 instead of 3.10 for the installation process (see code below)

```
install.packages("keras")
reticulate::install_miniconda()
keras::install_keras(method = "conda", python_version = "3.8")
```